# How can I run multiple selenium processes in parallel

Tags: selenium

I have a server that runs one selenium process at a time. I need to be able to run multiple selenium processes in parallel on that server. How can I do that?

Comment: The easiest way is just to create multiple instances of the driver.

Comment: @Jassmine can you mark Question as answered ? :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use Selenium Grid to run multiple selenium processes in parallel
http://elementalselenium.com/tips/52-grid

Answer (score 0):

If you want parallel execution for your selenium script then you can use TestNG.

http://testng.org/doc/index.html